# Make large amount of excel file

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I need your help,

Hi,

I have to find a solution in php in order to create a large amount of Excel File.

I make a huge amount of variable and put it in a Phpspreadsheet object.

But sometime the time to make only one Excel file is around 20 minutes. SO i need to start this function during the night. But i have a problem of memory and/or execution time .

It's a PHP backend server. It's not for users, only for administrators.

It's a loop with :
- Find the data in the Data Base (it take a lot of time)
- With the data, make the Excel File
- Export it

I would like to make all th request at the same time :)

is There a solution to make asynchronous function in order to make all the Excel file  at the same time and save it in the server ? (or a better solution).

Thank you very much for your futur help.